# Running client in Eclipse from a maven project for jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty

OK, so I got this monstrous maven web application for jetty, and I would like to run it's client. I have no maven or jetty experience (I have been developing too much with GWT/GAE).

The question is **WHERE** is the client code from the project structure below and **HOW** to run it in Eclipse (in localhost)

```
myProject
-->jetty-wrapper
   -->bin (with more inside)
   -->java (with more inside)
   -->src (with more inside)
   -->target
      -->myProject.jar
-->myProject-common
   -->bin (with more inside)
   -->src (with more inside)
   -->target
      -->myProject-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-->myProject-war
   -->bin (with more inside)
   -->src
      -->main
         -->webapp
            -->adminapp (inside you have css, fonts, img, includes, js and several jsp pages)
   -->bin (with more inside)
   -->target
      -->myProject-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (inside you have adminapp, ccverify, css, images, js, META-INF, protected, retired, WEB-INF and some html files)
      -->myProject-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I have already run 'mvn clean install'.

Thanks!

**----------------------------------------EDIT----------------------------**

I'll try to answer some questions from the comments. In general I don't know much about the project; I just "inherited" it like this.

**what's in jetty-wrapper?**

[image]
[image]

The server-side code is in *jetty-wrapper*. It uses Mongo. I've been able to execute an embedded Mongo with maven:

```
mvn clean install -Dembedmongo.wait
```

and then on another console (in jetty-wrapper -> target)

```
java -jar myProject.jar
```

**what's the point of java and src being different directories?** I don't know

**What version of jetty?** Version 9

**are you using jetty in embedded?** I don't know

**are you configuring jetty how? xml? spring?** I don't know how it's being configured

Comment: This can have hundreds of different answers (as it stands).  Can you provide more detail about what's in jetty-wrapper?  Things like: is there a main-class defined in the manifest? whats in the bin directory? what's the point of java and src being different directories? what does jetty-wrapper do?

Comment: client code could be in myProject-war, but would need more details about that to really know.

Comment: What version of jetty?  are you using jetty in embedded? or standalone? are you configuring jetty how? xml? spring? etc ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its embedded.

To verify, look for code that calls `"new Server"`, that would be your main entry point for the embedded server, and contain all of your server configuration.

As for the client, there's 2 possible things that stick out from your updates.

1. there's `myProjectCLI.java` that could have it (but i'd bet that's your `main-class` for how you start/configure your Jetty server.
2. there's lots of static content in your `target/work/webapp` (where it came from is still an unknown, but likely it arrived from some configuration in your maven `pom.xml` for that project), this project could be heavily GWT-like in behavior, with most of the client work being javascript/html.

You'll want to better understand the build.  What its dependencies are, what plugins it uses, what project module is dependent on what other project module (it might help explain the relationships between your projects better)

Comment: OK, and how do I actually run the client? Which kind of run configuration would it be? from which artifact should I launch it (i.e., from the project itself, from myProject-war)?